# Prove that if G is a nontrivial connected graph with at most two bridges

Tags: graph-theory

a nontrivial graph G has a strong orientation if and only if G is connected and contains no bridges.

Prove that if G is a nontrivial connected graph with at most two bridges then there exists an orientation D of G having the property that if u and v are any two vertices of D then there is either a u-v path or a v-u path.

Not sure how to do this question because I know if you have a bridge in a graph then it cannot be strongly connected.

So if you have a bridge you only have one edge and you cannot have both a uv and vu path in G so I confused.

Comment: The statement you are asked to prove only asks for an orientation, not a strong orientation, so it does not contradict the result in your first sentence.

Comment: I thought strong orientation meant that for every u,v in digraph G there is a uv and vu path, and they are asking for the same type of orientation

Comment: @FernandoMartinez No, you only need to show there is *either* a u-v path *or* a v-u path, which is different than strong connectivity which requires *both*.

Comment: The book I was reading says to do two case case 1 one bridge and case 2 equals two bridges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose there is exactly one bridge.
Then you can view the graph as two bridge-less subgraphs (land masses) joined by a single edge (the bridge). By the first line of your post, each bridge-less subgraph has a strong orientation, so use them as part of the orientation of the full graph. All that remains is the orientation of the bridge edge, which you may choose arbitrarily. Check that this satisfies your desired property.

The case with two bridges is similar. Here you will have three "land masses" and two bridges. You can follow the above argument again, but now the orientation of the two bridges cannot be chosen completely arbitrarily.

Comment: Ok so you just chose the orientation